# PullAsync now requires QueryId and results are no longer returning

Tags: windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I managed to get PullAsync working correctly in Azure Mobile Services 1.3.0-beta3 using

```
responseTypeTable.PullAsync(responseTypeTable.Where(c => c.CompanyId == companyId));
```

Then I upgraded to the first stable release over the weekend.

Now PullAsync requires a QueryId parameter as well as a the query. First I am confused as to why there would be a breaking change crossing beta3 to stable, I thought that the API should have well and truly been sorted by now, so maybe I am doing something wrong.

Anyway, I put in the Query Id as shown

```
responseTypeTable.PullAsync("QueryResponseTypePull",
                            responseTypeTable.Where(c => c.CompanyId == companyId));
```

The code compiles and runs and it even executes fine, hits the API but it doesn't return any values into the local store. When I run

```
result = await responseTypeTable.Where(c => c.CompanyId == companyId).ToListAsync();
```

to get the results from the local database it is always empty. This is the exact same code that was working prior to my update to 1.3.0 stable.

Comment: Ok, I reverted to beta3 (again the exact same code, I even left the QueryId in this time) and it all works perfectly. I'm going to have to stick with Beta3 for the moment I suppose until I find out what is causing this issue.

Comment: Try deleting your old database or using a new database filename. The format changed between beta3 and final. FYI, here's more info about the query ID: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/da1e81c0-4437-4ecd-a1cb-c8745faef522/breaking-change-in-mobile-services-offine-sync-version-13?forum=azuremobile

Comment: I did try a new database name as well just to test but the same result. I have ended up removing all Sync code from my project for the moment and gone back to direct api calls for the moment because of a deadline I am already past. I have upgraded to the stable release and at least all the direct API calls using the regular MobileServiceTable all works great. I will attempt the sync again in a few days once I have this project deployed.

Answer (score 6):

Providing QueryId causes the framework to download changes incrementally i.e. only updated data is downloaded since the last time you synced.

If you wish to download all the data every time you can pass null in place of QueryId and it will resort to full sync.

Comment: The initial load isn't even working. I currently have nothing in my local.db and the query it sends through to the API shows on any UpdatedAt > 1970-01-01 so it should be getting everything.

Comment: If you have .NET backend, you need to annotate the controller action with Queryable attribute. If it is node backend, then you need to have __updatedAt column in the table. Did you try the null queryId to resort to old behavior?

Comment: The closest I found was the [EnableQueryAttribute] attribute. Is this correct? The GetAll returns an IQueryable<ResponseType> but do I need the additional attribute?